# copy a value from one cell to another cell per row as "value" in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working in a Google sheet where I have several custom functions that geocode an address into lat/long details.
But I want to copy this value into another column on the same sheet as a value so the end result remain static.
I found a working piece of code that does this for an entire range but I can't get it dynamic so I can let it work for a single row and use the function per row where I need it.

Below is the code I have already.
So when I go to cell `N2` and call `=getRangeValues()`, it will copy the values for all fields from `M2` until `M9` into `N2:N9` but that's not what I want. I want it to only copy it for `M2` into `N2` for a single row.
I tried replacing the `getRange` into ActiveCell but that doesn't to the trick.

Anybody who can help me out with this?

```
function getRangeValues() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("M2:M9");
  var values = range.getValues();
  return values;
};
```

Comment: What do mean by "can't get it dynamic"? Does "I want it to only copy it for M2 into N2 for a single row" mean you want this function to always reference cells `M2` and `N2` or are you asking for a general solution to copy a value from one column to the neighboring column to the right for any given row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like that:

```
function getRangeValues() {
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  const cc = sheet.getCurrentCell();
  return sheet.getRange(cc.getRow(),cc.getColumn()-1).getValue();
};
```

If you **click** on a particular cell and enter the formula: `=getRangeValues()` it will give you the value of the left cell in the **same** row:

[image: example]